# Won't print error message. It worked fine in python 2 but wont when i try and change it to python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x

Program won't post error messages. It worked fine in python 2 and when I try and convert it, it won't work.

```
def getData(filename):
    """Create Database with raw text as the entries.
    """
    with open(filename, 'r') as f
        reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel-tab')  
        dat = []
        for row in reader:
            if len(row) != 4: 
               sys.exit("\nInput read error!\nData file incomplete!\n")
            if '' in row:
               sys.exit("\nInput read error!\nEmpty field found!\n")
            dat.append(row)
        dat = dat[1:]                                                   
        return dat
```

Comment: How does it not work? (By the way, exclamation marks in error messages are usually not a good idea.)

Comment: Is this your whole code? Where are `row` and `sys` defined?

Comment: Can not reproduce. Using Python3 and the usual `sys` module, `exit` prints the given message before exiting. Are you sure those lines are executed? Maybe the program exits some other way?

Comment: Show us your whole code.

Comment: Added the whole part. The program is too big to put it all on here.

Comment: Anyway, I'd suggest you change those `sys.exit` to just raising an exception, and then exit the program from your main method. I don't think exiting the entire program from some helper method is good practice.

Comment: There aren't any problems with the function that I can see. Please provide a [short, self-contained, runnable example](http://www.sscce.org/) that exhibits your problem.

Comment: @tobias_k okay i'll try that, i'm just trying to show that i can use modules from the standard library as well. Could you please put an example as i'm not overly sure what you mean. Thanks

Comment: My suggestion was just to raise an exception in the method and then handle that exception (exiting the system) on a higher level. This won't solve your problem, it was just a remark (and merely my opinion) about style.